# How to edit profile ? (using devise and has a model Profile but edit method is giving error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using devise and has created a model profile.

I have added the has_one relationship to user and belongs_to :user to profile model. I have also added user_id column in profile.

I have also added

```
before_filter :create_profile
def create_profile 
  profile = Profile.create
end
```

in User model. When a new user registers it a new profile do gets created. So if the user id is 10, this is what is getting created in profile

```
#<Profile id: 2, name: nil, created_at: "2013-08-17 06:44:33", updated_at: "2013-08-17 06:47:00", user_id: 10>
```

Now the problem is, I have put an edit link in application.rb

```
<li><%= link_to "Profile".html_safe, edit_profile_path(current_user) %></li>
```

but it is giving error

```
Couldn't find Profile with id=10
```

so instead of searching for id=2, it is looking at user_id, how to fix this ? I am sure I am missing out on something very small but not sure what.

EDIT - the error is coming from this line @profile = Profile.find(params[:id]) in edit method

```
# profiles_controller.rb
def edit
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end
```

I have tried to use :user_id and :profile_id but that also gave error "Couldn't find Profile without an ID"

**EDIT 2-**

routes.rb has, it is pretty much blank

```
resources :profiles
```

rake routes output (the other paths are devise standard paths)

```
                profiles GET        /profiles(.:format)                                     profiles#index
                         POST       /profiles(.:format)                                     profiles#create
             new_profile GET        /profiles/new(.:format)                                 profiles#new
            edit_profile GET        /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)                            profiles#edit
                 profile GET        /profiles/:id(.:format)                                 profiles#show
                         PUT        /profiles/:id(.:format)                                 profiles#update
                         DELETE     /profiles/:id(.:format)                                 profiles#destroy
```

profiles_controller.rb , the other 5 methods are standard once

```
  def edit
    @user = current_user
    @profile = @user.profiles.find(params[:profile_id])

  end

  def create

    @profile = current_user.build_profile(params[:profile])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'User profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @profile, status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First fix your user model:

```
before_filter :create_profile
def create_profile 
  profile = Profile.create
end
```

should be:

```
after_create :create_profile

def create_profile
  self.profile.create
end
```

before_filter is for controllers, not for models!

Second: Change this line

```
<li><%= link_to "Profile".html_safe, edit_profile_path(current_user) %></li>
```

to this one:

```
<li><%= link_to "Profile", edit_profile_path(current_user.profile) %></li>
```

Third: Change your controller edit action:

```
def edit
  @profile = current_user.profile
end
```

I think you could remove the create action from your profiles_controller, because you have the before_create hook in your user model which creates the profile.

Your routes

```
resources :profiles
```

just provides you an id parameter for the edit action, and that´s the id from the profile, and not from the user. You could add one through nested routes for the current_user, but that´s not necessary, because you already have the current_user method from devise which returns you the current logged in user.

btw:

```
"Profile".html_safe
```

=> is not necessary.

```
"<h1>Profile</h1>".html_safe
```

=> would be necessary.

Comment: Hi, well I am getting this error "No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil}" and I am using edit_profile_path(@profile) in application.html.erb, also rake routes also shows -  edit_profile GET        /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)                            profiles#edit
 so the path also exist

Comment: Change @profile to current_user.profile (you should set the at-profile instance variable in the controller action, which gets called to show the page which contains the edit link). If current_user.profile returns nothing, your user does not have any profile yet..

Comment: sorry couldn't get it, what should I edit in profiles_controller.rb ? also where should I set it ? I think we are almost there

Comment: great, I have set edit_profile_path(current_user.profile) and we have made progress as now the path is right, but now I am seeing "undefined method `profiles' for #<User:0xbe96adc>", in profiles_controller.rb file on thsi line "@profile = current_user.profiles.find(params[:id])"

Comment: ah you have a has_one association, change it to this line: @profile = current_user.profile. I will update my answer.

Comment: awesome, now it is working, one last thing, when the profile is getting created, its user_id is blank, should I make   def "create_profile
    profile = current_user.profiles.create
  end" in user.rb ?

Comment: naah, profile = current_user.profiles.create in user.rb is giving "undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<User:0xc5258f8>" error, so how to set user_id in profile ?

Comment: I updated my answer. take a look at the first step of my answer. I changed the current_user to self, because you are within the model scope and the current instance is the current_user - self.. if it does not work, let´s move to chat ;)

Comment: I am getting "undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35659/discussion-between-icyborg-and-mattherick)

Comment: also should I remove the create method in profile_controller.rb ?

Answer (score 2):

If devise already provide edit functionality then why you need to maintain profile just for edit still if you need it you should not add user_id column in profile it should come User.

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "edit", edit_user_registration_path(current_user) %>
```

Comment: Hi, well this is taking me to user edit form, I need to go to profile edit form

Comment: ok then def a method for edit in profile controller and follow the dax answer for views.

Comment: you haven't created a profile yet. create a new profile first

Comment: I checked, the profile is certainly getting created though yes, the user_id was nil so I manually had to change it through rails console. Still when all the data is there, and after putting dax's code, I am getting the error "undefined method `profiles' for #<Class:0xb459b8c>"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your controller looks like, but you can explicitly tell rails where to find the profile_id.  something like this:

```
<li><%= link_to "Profile".html_safe, edit_profile_path(current_user, profile_id: @profile) %></li>
```

**Edit**:
`#<Class:0xb459b8c>` is the whole user class, not an instance which is why you can't call `profiles` on it.  try this:

```
@user = current_user
@profile = @user.profiles.find(params[:profile_id])
```

**Edit 2**:

According to your original question:

> the problem is, I have put an edit link in application.rb
>
> `<li><%= link_to "Profile".html_safe, edit_profile_path(current_user) %></li>`
>
> but it is giving error
>
> `Couldn't find Profile with id=10`
>
> so instead of searching for id=2, it is looking at user_id, how to fix this ?

The problem, i think, is here:

```
`<li><%= link_to "Profile".html_safe, edit_profile_path(current_user) %></li>`
```

your `edit_profile_path' calls for

```
/profiles/:id/edit(.:format)
```

that `:id` is the :id of the `profile` table, not the `user` table - so your `link_to` should look like this:

`<li><%= link_to "Profile".html_safe, edit_profile_path(id: @profile.id) %></li>`

or just

`<li><%= link_to "Profile".html_safe, edit_profile_path(@profile) %></li>`

and your controller should look like this (how it did originally):

```
# profiles_controller.rb
def edit
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end
```

which will give your routes what they want.

Comment: I am still having the same error, "Couldn't find Profile with id", the error is coming on this line in edit method (as shown above)   
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])

Comment: now getting this error "undefined method `profiles' for #<Class:0xb459b8c>", I have also tried current_user.profiles..find(params[:profile_id]) and user.profiles.find(params[:profile_id]), still same error. I checked at rails console and all the data is there so the only problem is we don't have the correct syntax to call the profile edit

Comment: I am still getting the error "undefined method `profiles' for #<User:0xc385034>", do also note that "profile" link is linking to "/profiles/30/edit" where 30 is user_id, the profile_id is 8. I did checked the Profile table in rails console the user_id column certainly has user_id = 30 for profile_id 8

Comment: could you add your routes.rb file, output of `$ rake routes`, and the relevant controller?

Comment: Hi, I have added all the code, I created profile using scaffold and have only edited edit and create methods. I have create_profile method in user.rb model whose code I have put it above. The routes are all standard too.

Comment: sorry I was out, just came back, I just put the code, now I am getting this error "No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil}", I am using <li><%= link_to "Profile".html_safe, edit_profile_path(@profile) %></li> in application.html.erb

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35652/discussion-between-icyborg-and-dax)